# Getting the longest common subsequence in ERLANG

Tags: string, function, erlang, lcs

I'm new to this ERLANG, I know the basics. It's like scheme but broader. I know how to create a function but I'm having problems with creating a function that gets the Longest Common Subsequence.

`lcs(str1,str2)` is a function that will accept two string and output an integer:

`lcs(algorithm,logarithm)` will output `7` because the longest common subsequence that can be made is `lgrithm` which is `7` in size.

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a pretty good implementation of an LCS algorithm available on [Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Erlang), which is:

```
-module(lcs).
-compile(export_all).

lcs_length(S,T) ->
    {L,_C} = lcs_length(S,T,dict:new()),
    L.

lcs_length([]=S,T,Cache) ->
    {0,dict:store({S,T},0,Cache)};
lcs_length(S,[]=T,Cache) ->
    {0,dict:store({S,T},0,Cache)};
lcs_length([H|ST]=S,[H|TT]=T,Cache) ->
    {L,C} = lcs_length(ST,TT,Cache),
    {L+1,dict:store({S,T},L+1,C)};
lcs_length([_SH|ST]=S,[_TH|TT]=T,Cache) ->
    case dict:is_key({S,T},Cache) of
        true -> {dict:fetch({S,T},Cache),Cache};
        false ->
            {L1,C1} = lcs_length(S,TT,Cache),
            {L2,C2} = lcs_length(ST,T,C1),
            L = lists:max([L1,L2]),
            {L,dict:store({S,T},L,C2)}
    end.

lcs(S,T) ->
    {_,C} = lcs_length(S,T,dict:new()),
    lcs(S,T,C,[]).

lcs([],_,_,Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
lcs(_,[],_,Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
lcs([H|ST],[H|TT],Cache,Acc) ->
    lcs(ST,TT,Cache,[H|Acc]);
lcs([_SH|ST]=S,[_TH|TT]=T,Cache,Acc) ->
    case dict:fetch({S,TT},Cache) > dict:fetch({ST,T},Cache) of
        true ->
            lcs(S,TT,Cache, Acc);
        false ->
            lcs(ST,T,Cache,Acc)
    end.
```

Used as:

```
raringbeast:Code pierre $ erl
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe]
[kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c(lcs).
{ok,lcs}
2> lcs:lcs("logarithm", "algorithm").
"lgrithm"
3> lcs:lcs_length("logarithm", "algorithm").
7
```

--

**Edit: Made the algorithm a little easier to understand**

The cache here is just an interesting way to improve algorithm performance in some cases, but this isn't required here. We can just write, removing the cache:

```
lcs_length([],_T) ->
    0;
lcs_length(_S,[]) ->
    0;
lcs_length([_H|ST],[_H|TT]) ->
    1 + lcs_length(ST,TT);
lcs_length([_SH|ST]=S,[_TH|TT]=T) ->
    L1 = lcs_length(S,TT),
    L2 = lcs_length(ST,T),
    lists:max([L1,L2]).
```

To sum up:

1. The LCS of "" and anything is 0.
2. Same for the LCS of anything and "".
3. The LCS of two words starting by the same letter is the LCS of the two words minus the first letter plus 1.
4. The LCS of two words starting by different letters is the max of (a) the LCS of the first word minus the first letter and the second, and (b) the LCS of the first word and the second minus the first letter.

Comment: Nice, thanks. didn't notice that source. This is good but can you give me a simpler implementation of lcs in erlang? It seems to be complicated.

Comment: Or could you explain line by line the implementation above?

Comment: I just edited my post with an simpler version of the algorithm (removing the cache), and explained the 4 cases taken in account. This should be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, bro. Above implementation just made it easier to understand. I didn't know lcs could be simple as that. Learned a lot. Sorry for the late replies, btw.