# longest substring in ERLANG

Tags: string, erlang

I'm trying to make a function as this:

- input: some strings (example: "thisis_a_string123", "thisis_a_nother_string123", "thisis_not_a_string123")
- ouput: a longest substring counted from the 1st character (example: "thisis_"), if not found, return an empty string: "".

Since the output is only: "thisis_", not a Longest Common Subsequence like this: "thisis_a_string123", so it is different with: 
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence

and this:
[Getting the longest common subsequence in ERLANG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920564/getting-the-longest-common-subsequence-in-erlang)

any help will be appreciated, thank you !!

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code for this yet? Can you post it?

Comment: @Dogbert: I'm trying, but not yet find any solution...

Comment: What are you trying so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the longest common *prefix*, not substring. This can be done by first defining a function that works with 2 lists:

```
lcp([X | XS], [X | YS]) ->
  [X | lcp(XS, YS)];
lcp(_, _) ->
  [].
```

Then using `lists:foldl` to apply it to a list of lists:

```
lcp([X | XS]) ->
  lists:foldl(fun lcp/2, X, XS).
```

```
1> a:lcp(["thisis_a_string123", "thisis_a_nother_string123", "thisis_not_a_string123"]).
"thisis_"
2> a:lcp(["thisis_a_string123", "thisis_a_nother_string123", "thisis_not_a_string123", "xyz"]).
[]
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for !! thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

For any number of strings:

```
lcp([]) -> [];
lcp([S]) -> S;
lcp(L) -> lcp_(L).

lcp_([[H|T]|R]) ->
  case strip(H, R, []) of
    false -> [];
    Ts -> [H|lcp_([T|Ts])]
  end.

strip(_, [], Ts) -> Ts;
strip(H, [[H|T]|R], Ts) -> strip(H, R, [T|Ts]);
strip(_, _, _) -> false.
```